# Maximum subgraph matching

Tags: pattern-matching, graph-theory

Given two graphs `G=(V,E)`, for example:

[image: G]

and `G'=(V',E')`, for example:

[image: G']

I need to find the maximum subgraph matching between them. Consider `G` as the target graph and `G'` as the quay graph. Each node and each edge has a set of attributes, but this is not too relevant as I have a function that given two nodes (or two edges) it will return a value representing the similarity between both elements (higher value, higher similarity).

The maximum matching matching will be the match with the highest similarity, in that case, as we have 2 nodes and 1 edge as query, the addition of the similarity values for that 2 nodes and 1 edge with the elements in the target graph (`G`) should be maximum.

Doing this by brute-force will return the proper solution, but it's too hard to compute, so I'm open to not the the global maximum but a good solution (like a Greedy algorithm or an algorithm that is guided by something to perform the search) but the algorithm should return the best value without compromising the compute time.

Comment: Wouldn't that be a reformulation of the [max-cut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_cut) problem ?

Comment: The optimal solution will be impossible to get for big instances since it is a NP-hard problem.

Comment: Can you suggest a non-optimal algorithm? @m.raynal

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is similar to the [maximum cut problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_cut). Since the problem is NP-hard, you can't expect a polynomial-time algorithm that would return an optimal answer unless P=NP.
But there exist several approximation algorithm. Among those, there is a `1/2`-approximation greedy algorithm, which is very simple to implement.
It is described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_cut#Approximation_algorithms), and is a simple greedy algorithm where you start with a random partition of the vertex set, and then move vertices from one set to the other if it improves the cut. Once you can't improve the current solution anymore, you have the approximate solution.

Comment: How can I handle comparing the edges at the same times as nodes? @m.raynal

Answer (score 0):

Try some algorithms of **total covering**

Actually your problem can't have polynomial-time algorithm that will get you "THE" answer
You still can explore many others viable solution

(backtracking maybe ?)

Comment: Can you suggest me some/any of those other viable solutions? @Dinger

Comment: the algorithms are supposed to suggest you these "other viable solution" regarding the NP character of this problem, we can't say if it's "the best" , try to apply some backtracking algorithm